# bat script to parse a build.properties file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a build.properties file that looks like this:

```
ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER=1.7.0
ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER=11
ELECTRON_MAC_VERSION_NUMBER=1.7.0
ELECTRON_MAC_BUILD_NUMBER=11
```

i have a runme.bat script that looks like this:

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ("build.properties") DO (
    IF "%%A"=="ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER" set ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER" set ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER=%%B
)

echo "%ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER%"
echo "%ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER%"
```

When it runs it outputs this:

```
""
""
```

What am I doing wrong that it does not output:

```
"1.7.0"
"11"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What am I doing wrong?

Your `for` command is parsing the string `"build.properties"` and not the contents of the file `build.properties`.

Remove the quotes.

Corrected batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (build.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER" set ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER" set ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER=%%B
)

echo "%ELECTRON_WIN_VERSION_NUMBER%"
echo "%ELECTRON_WIN_BUILD_NUMBER%"
```

Output:

```
> test
"1.7.0"
"11"
>
```

#### What do I do if the file name contains spaces?

In this case you can use `type` to return the contents of the file for `for` to parse:

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ('type "build space.properties"') DO (
```

Notes:

- Single quotes `'` are used to indicate that a command is to be processed.
- Double quotes `"` are used to delimit the file name that contains spaces.

You can also use the `for` option `usebackq`:

```
usebackq     Use the alternate quoting style:                        
                   - Use double quotes for long file names in "filenameset".
                   - Use single quotes for 'Text string to process'
                   - Use back quotes for `command_to_process`
```

Then the `for` command becomes:

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ("build space.properties") DO (
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I am in the habit of putting Quotes around file names to handle the general case of spaces in the filename.  Would this code be modified if the filename had a space?

Comment: @MichaelPotter See updated answer.

Comment: You do not need to use the TYPE command. That is what the USEBACKQ option is for.

Comment: @Squashman Correct, as usual there are many different ways of solving batch problems ... particularly when it involves `for` loops ... answer updated.